# solr filter effects seen in analyzer but not score

Tags: solr, filter, lucene, frequency, deduplication

As part of my fieldType definition I have a filter as can be found here https://github.com/gaillard/solr-filter-dedup that will deduplicate tokens in that field.

When I use the solr analyzer I see duplicate terms being removed for the indexer, so it appears to be working correctly. However when I run a real query and look at the term frequencies in the solr debug for the top scoring document, it appears to be counting all my terms.

Why is the effect of the filter not being seen in the scoring?

Comment: Have you reindexed after adding the filter?